# Make random parts of a text clickable without textSpan in flutter

Tags: flutter

Make random parts of a text clickable in flutter without textSpan because when I change the language the order of words also changes. For the textSpan, we know the order of texts matters.

I have user agreement text below in Turkish and Kyrgyz languages. If Locale is in Turkish, Turkish user agreement should be visible, otherwise, Kyrgyz user agreement.

Sample texts:

1. Кирүүнү басуу менен мен **Тейлөө шарттарына макулмун**.
2. Enter'a tıklayarak **Hizmet Şartlarını** kabul ediyorum

Comment: You can create textspans also in a dynamic way so the order doesn't matter much. Can you maybe provide example sentences?

Comment: I have provided sample texts above

Comment: Ok, I will write an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way I would do it is to somehow mark the clickable part, for example by enclosing it in `{}`. You can then do this for example:

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: Column(
    children: const [
      TextWithLink(
          text: "Кирүүнү басуу менен мен {Тейлөө шарттарына макулмун}"),
      TextWithLink(
          text: "Enter'a tıklayarak {Hizmet Şartlarını} kabul ediyorum")
    ],
  )));
}

class TextWithLink extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  static final regex = RegExp("(?={)|(?<=})");

  const TextWithLink({Key? key, required this.text}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final split = text.split(regex);
    return RichText(
        text: TextSpan(
      children: <InlineSpan>[
        for (String text in split)
          text.startsWith('{')
              ? TextSpan(
                  text: text.substring(1, text.length - 1),
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      decoration: TextDecoration.underline, color: Colors.blue),
                  recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                    ..onTap = () => print("click"),
                )
              : TextSpan(text: text),
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]