# Flutter - Find replace and style certain string pattern in a list

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-widget

I have a list of strings that loaded from json file as below:

It was getting [color="black"]dark[/color], and we weren’t [color="blue"]there[/color] yet. 
They got [color="black"]there[/color] early, and they got really [color="black"]good[/color] seats. 
Mr. Montoya knows the way to the [color="black"]bakery[/color] even though he's never been [color="blue"]there[/color].

How to use listview.builder to find each text that is wrap within [color="..."][/color] and add text style color or Widget to it? 
For example [color="blue"]there[/color] become there (with color blue)

Comment: Why listview.builder? you want each word on a different row?

Comment: I would learn how to read json file in flutter and just made widget for the case you have. I would prepare json in right format so I can easly read text and assosiated color.

Comment: @Ivo, because it is the list of sentences and in each sentence there are some [color="..."] tag. That's why i need to use listview to populate the list and then use some logic to search for [color="..."] and replace it with widget

Comment: @sonic, can you elaborate more

Comment: my bad you want to parse strings. So propably u need to write some RegEx that will change your [color="color']zxcz[/color] pattern to something that flutter can render

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working example. Not sure if it's the best way, because it's a bit hacky but gets the job done:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  List<String> sentences = [
    'It was getting [color="black"]dark[/color], and we weren’t [color="blue"]there[/color] yet.',
    'They got [color="black"]there[/color] early, and they got really [color="black"]good[/color] seats.',
    '''Mr. Montoya knows the way to the [color="black"]bakery[/color] even though he's never been [color="blue"]there[/color].'''
  ];

  runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
    body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: sentences.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: TextWithColors(text: sentences[index]),
            )),
  )));
}

class TextWithColors extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  static final regex = RegExp("(?=\\[)|(?<=\\])");

  const TextWithColors({Key? key, required this.text}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final split = text.split(regex);
    Color currentColor = Colors.grey;
    return RichText(
        text: TextSpan(
      children: <InlineSpan>[
        for (String text in split)
          text.startsWith('[')
              ? TextSpan(
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: currentColor = text.contains('"black"')
                          ? Colors.black
                          : text.contains('"blue"')
                              ? Colors.blue
                              : Colors.grey))
              : TextSpan(text: text, style: TextStyle(color: currentColor)),
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: It is close to what I need. Beside add the color to the text, can I wrap those color text into gesture detection widget? To make it clickable as well?

Comment: @JovenDev yeah you can do that with TextSpans as well. See here to get an idea of how that might work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73485675/make-random-parts-of-a-text-clickable-without-textspan-in-flutter . But it might become quite complicated to implement the logic for that

Comment: in that example how text: text.substring(1, text.length - 1) can be apply in my code? because I need to get the "color" text and wrap it in gesture detection widget

Answer (score 0):

You need to use regular expression that will change your strings into multiple TextSpan's that you can combine. so your `[color=black]black[/color]`
will become

`TextSpan(text: 'black', style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black))`

I took it from other stackoverflow question

> You should use the RichText widget.
>
> A RichText widget will take in a TextSpan widget that can also have a
> list of children TextSpans.
>
> Each TextSpan widget can have a different TextStyle.
>
> Here is the example code to render: Hello World
>
> ```
> var text = RichText(
>   text: TextSpan(
>     // Note: Styles for TextSpans must be explicitly defined.
>     // Child text spans will inherit styles from parent
>     style: const TextStyle(
>       fontSize: 14.0,
>       color: Colors.black,
>     ),
>     children: <TextSpan>[
>       TextSpan(text: 'Hello'),
>       TextSpan(text: 'World', style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
>     ],
>   ),
> );
> ```