# How to Bold, Italic, underline, attach hyperlink dynamic text without using RichText Widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, text

**How to Bold, Italic, underline, attach hyperlink dynamic text**

example: when we add description in **stackoverflow** and **trello**

**My Input:**
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ma15g.png)

**Output that I want:**
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlXOl.png)

Comment: Why don't you want to use `RichText`?

Comment: because the text is dynamic and i am getting from the server

Comment: Well, you could still make it with RichText dynamically as well, but it might be complicated. In any case, I think the kind of formatting you want is Markdown formatting. There are packages that handle that like this one: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_markdown . I haven't tried it but maybe it works for you

Comment: for example when we are creating description in stackoverflow we bold the text with ** [text] **

Comment: Here are some examples of dynamic `RichText` usage https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73485675/make-random-parts-of-a-text-clickable-without-textspan-in-flutter or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74346786/change-numbers-only-font-family-in-flutter . You might be able to alter them to fit your need, but I agree it might become very complicated to handle all separate cases of bold, italic, underline and hyperlink. But I think the package I linked before might work for you

Comment: @FahadSaleem have you check this : https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html

Comment: Yeah I want markdown formatting. Thanks i think it will work for me perfectly

Comment: @rahulVFlutterAndroid yeah i checked that but i am getting markdown format from server and this package will work with html tags. example <h1>heading 1</h1> but i need #heading 1